# How to set the proxy port and URL in R for the blsAPI

Tags: r, proxy, port, quandl

My employer's firewall requires I set the proxy port and url when downloading data in R using the Quandl package. I'm now trying to use the blsAPI package and the work around I used for Quandl is not working. How do I set the proxy port and URL for the blsAPI package?

Below see the code I use for Quandl:

```
proxyURL <- "##.#.##.###"
proxyPort <- ####,
set_config(use_proxy(url = proxyURL, proxyPort))
```

Below see the error I get using the blsAPI:

```
> response <- blsAPI('LAUCN040010000000005')
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to api.bls.gov port 80: Timed out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, see code below:

```
proxyURL <- "##.#.##.###"
proxyPort <- ####
Sys.setenv(http_proxy = paste(proxyURL, proxyPort, sep = ":"))
```

I can now use the blsAPI.